# SQL string format with quotes

Tags: sql, vb.net, text

If u have a text ( mostly sql query ) and you want to put prefix on each line something like

sQ &= " And at the end of line "

Something like this.

```
SELECT 
       Name,Age 
FROM
       Users 
Where 
       id<>0
```

I want

```
 sQ &=" SELECT "
 sQ &="       Name,Age "
 sQ &=" FROM"
 sQ &="        Users "
 sQ &=" Where "
 sQ &="        id<>0"
```

If possible to keep it formated if not who cares.

I need this because i use vb.net and mostly i work with queries.

Comment: You can do it with any text editor that supports column selection such as Sublime Text

Comment: What I usually do is paste the sql query in a excel spreadsheet, then the next column I just add the &. Buy I advise you to create a method that returns that as a string instead of concatenating at each line. If you isolate to a method, it will be much easier to visualize later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Nimbletext. Add it your external tools for VS and SSMS.

A pattern of `sql &=" $0 "` gives the results you want. Tools, Options... turns trim off

Comment: Just noticed there is an online version on their web site - try it out!

Comment: Note that is an unusual way to use the tool - really shines on row operations e.g. paste a CSV list in the top and add a pattern for an SQL INSERT to quickly update rows via PK and new values.

Answer (score 0):

Just hold down the <kbd>ALT</kbd>-Key, click the mouse on the last line and *draw* your cursor up to the first line. Now you're in *Multiline*-Editmode which allows you to edit multiple lines at once.

Answer (score 0):

In bash you can use awk:

--add prefix and suffix to each line a text file

```
 awk '{ printf("sQ &=" %s "", $l);}' sample-text-file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep formatting when you show the query (for example in a textbox) you may simply do something like:

```
Me.TextBox1.text = sQ.Replace("    ", VbCrLf & "    ")
```

(there are 4 spaces between the quotes)